# Prove $\dfrac13\geq$ $|1/(z^2-1)|$ for every z on the circle $C(0,2)$

Tags: complex-analysis

Prove :

$\dfrac13\geq|1/(z^2-1)|$ for every $z$ on the circle $C(0,2)$

by the reverse triangle inequality: $|z_1-z_2|^2 \geq |z_1|^2-|z_2|^2$

Answer (score 1):

If
$|z| = 2$,
then
$|z|^2 = 4$
so
$|z|^2-1 = 3$
so
$|z^2-1|
\ge |z|^2-1
=3
$,
so,
taking reciprocals
$\dfrac1{|z^2-1|}
\le \dfrac13
$.

Answer (score 0):

Reverse triangle inequality is $|z_1-z_2|\geq|z_1|-|z_2|.$

For $z \in C(0,2)$ one has $|z|=2,$ thus
$$|z^2-1| \geq |z^2|-|1|=|z|^2-1=3.$$